# How to create a scheduled task to run on system startup(without user logging in) in Windows server 2016 azure vm

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have a windows server 2016 server in Azure which is mainly used for running a few scripts.

I want to create a schedule where a script should run at the system startup(around 3-5 mins delay is also fine, not more)

I had tried task scheduler with different settings, both at startup and delay by 10 mins (in Actions), but it isn't working as the task is not starting at startup even after a delay of 10 mins.

So, how to schedule a task to run a script at startup even without the user logging in?

Comment: Does the history of the task say anything?

Comment: Did you tried to choose an option "Run whether user is logged or not"? Also may be "run with highest privileges" checkbox would help.

Comment: Hi @Nixphoe, History just shows the task is started, 

Task Scheduler started "{0e04202c-3a71-428c-9616-27b44b89259d}" instance of the "\Test" task for user "DOMAIN\user".

Comment: Hi @warder, Yes Have tried those also but not able to get it working